# Time and space complexity of this function to print binary tree level by level

Tags: java, binary-tree, big-o, time-complexity, space-complexity

This algorithm is for printing a common binary tree level by level.

What is the time complexity and space complexity of `printSpecificLevel_BT()` and `printBT_LBL()`?

I think `printSpecificLevel_BT`'s time complexity is `O(lg N)`, and space complexity is `O(lg N)`.
I think `printBT_LBL()`'s time complexity is `O((lgN)^2)`, and the space complexity is `O((lgN)^2)`.

Is this correct?

```
// Print the specific level of a binary tree.
public static void printSpecificLevel_BT (Node root, int level) {
    if (root == null) return;
    if (level == 0) System.out.print(String.format("%-6d", root.data)); // Base case.
    // Do recrusion.
    printSpecificLevel_BT(root.leftCh, level - 1);
    printSpecificLevel_BT(root.rightCh, level - 1);
}

// Get the height of a binary tree.
public static int getHeight_BT (Node root) {
    if (root == null || (root.leftCh == null && root.rightCh == null)) return 0; // Base case.
    return 1 + Math.max (getHeight_BT(root.leftCh), getHeight_BT(root.rightCh));
}

// Print a binary tree level by level.
public static void printBT_LBL (Node root) {
    // Get the height of this binary tree.
    int height = getHeight_BT(root);
    for (int i = 0; i <= height; i ++) {
        printSpecificLevel_BT(root, i);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do *you* think it is?

Comment: I think "printSpecificLevel_BT"'s time complexity = O(lgN), and the space complexity = O(lgN). The "printBT_LBL()"'s time complexity = O((lgN)^2), and the space complexity = O((lgN)^2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printSpecificLevel_BT` is `O(n)` since it looks at every node in the tree. However, with a simply change (returning when `level == 0`), you can make it `O(min(n, 2^level))`.

`getHeight` is `O(n)` since it looks at every node in the tree. `printBT_LBL` calls `getHeight` once and `printSpecificLevel_BT` `height` times, so its complexity is `O(n + n*height) = O(n*height)`.

The space complexity of each is `O(height)` since it recurses all the way to the bottom of the tree. You can't say the `O(log n)` since the tree isn't necessarily balanced (unless it is).

Comment: Hi, Dukeling, thank you so much. But personally I think, since it is binary tree, 2^level >= n. And what's about the space complexity. It seems not obviously. May I ask you another question: "Is there a better way to print a common binary tree level by level". Thank you so much.

Comment: See edit. It's actually more like `O(min(n, 2^level))`. Consider when `level = 0`, for example, then `2^level = 1`, which is most likely much less than `n`. At the cost of space complexity, you could construct an array of linked-lists / arrays and put all nodes in the tree into this structure at the appropriate index (corresponding to the level) for the second function. You can't do much better for the first function.

Answer (score 1):

For `printSpecificLevel_BT()` you have:

[image]

For `printBT_LBL()` you have:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Amazing answer!!!! Thank you so much! Your answer lets me recall the "Introduction to Algorithms"........